# Fusing conjugacy classes

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Consider a finite group $G$ and two conjugacy classes $H$ and $I$ of isomorphic subgroups of $G$.

> **Question.** Is there some finite overgroup of $G$ which fuses $H$ and $I$ into a single conjugacy class?

Comment: You are asking about finite overgroups. But just to note that with [HNN extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension) you can find an infinite overgroup of $G$ where $H$ and $I$ are conjugate.

Comment: If $H$ and $I$ are cyclic, embedding $G$ into $S_{|G|}$ with the regular permutation representation works. Would that work for any $H$ and $I$?

Comment: @spin Yes - $G$ is a union of $|G|/|H| = |G|/|I|$ orbits of $H$ with trivial stabilizer, and also the union of the same number of orbits of $I$ with trivial stabilizer. These are isomorphic, giving an element in $S_{|G|}$ conjugating one to the other.

Comment: $H,I$ are conjugacy classes of subgroups (hence are sets of subgroups), or are subgroups?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning a less direct/constructive point of view that fits into a broader conceptual framework. As mentioned by @spin, the "universal" method of making $H$ and $I$ isomorphic produces the HNN extension $\Gamma=G*_{H\sim I}$. This is always infinite, but for $G$ finite it is not too hard to prove (using ideas similar to Will Sawin's comment) that $\Gamma$ is virtually free, and hence residually finite. Once you know $\Gamma$ is residually finite, it has a finite quotient into which $G$ embeds, and this is the group you want.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes, as noted in the comments above by Will Sawin.

Let $H$ and $I$ be isomorphic subgroups of the finite group $G$.

Consider the regular permutation representation $G \leq \operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega = G$. Then for $H$ and $I$ the action on $\Omega$ splits into $[G:H] = [G:I]$ orbits. Furthermore, for both groups the action on every orbit is regular. So since $H$ and $I$ are isomorphic, their actions on $\Omega$ are equivalent, which means that they are conjugate in $\operatorname{Sym}(\Omega)$.

In general, for any group $G$, with [HNN extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension) you can find an infinite overgroup $G^*$ of $G$ such that $H$ and $I$ are conjugate in $G^*$.