# Fusing conjugacy classes II

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, conjugacy-classes

(Followup to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391434/fusing-conjugacy-classes))

Consider a finite-dimensional Lie group $G$ and two conjugacy classes $H$ and $I$ of isomorphic subgroups of $G$.

> **Question.** Is there some finite-dimensional Lie overgroup of $G$ which fuses $H$ and $I$ into a single conjugacy class?

Answer (score 4):

No. Take $G={\rm SL}(2,{\Bbb R})$, $\ H=\{\,h(\lambda)={\rm diag}(\lambda, \lambda^{-1})\ |\  \lambda\in {\Bbb R}, \lambda>0\,\}$,
$$U=\bigg\{ u(a)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &a\\ 0&1
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \bigg|\ \ a\in {\Bbb R}\ \bigg\}.$$
The Lie groups $U$ and $H$ are isomorphic
via the isomorphism $u(a)\mapsto h(e^a)$.

In any Lie overgroup $G'$ containing $G$, the subgroups $H$ and $U$ of $G$ act on $L' ={\rm Lie\,}G'$ via a smooth finite dimensional representation
$${\rm Ad}\colon\, G\hookrightarrow G'\to {\rm GL}(L').$$
of the Lie group $G$. Since any such representation of $G$ is polynomial (I don't know a reference!), we see that each element of ${\rm Ad}(U)$ is unipotent (has all eigenvalues 1), whereas each element of ${\rm Ad}(H)$ is semisimple. We conclude that ${\rm Ad}(U)$ and ${\rm Ad}(H)$ are not conjugate in ${\rm GL}(L')$, and therefore $U$ and $H$ are not conjugate in $G'$.

Comment: This is a great example!  Maybe I'm underthinking or overcomplicating it, but doesn't polynomial-ity follow from the fact that the finite-dimensional representations of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \mathbb R)$ are explicitly described, and can be seen to be polynomial?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes, it does, but I don't know a reference.